# Call an Erlang function to create a user in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using erlang 18, ejabberd 15.09. I am trying to create chat application. For that I have to create user for ejabberd using Erlang. 
I used the erlang function `ejabberd_auth:try_register` for that:

```
ejabberd_auth:try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>).
```

It produced the following error：

> exception error: undefined function stringprep:nameprep/1
>        in function  jlib:nameprep/1 (src/jlib.erl, line 331)
>        in call from ejabberd_auth:auth_modules/1 (src/ejabberd_auth.erl, line 429) 
>        in call from ejabberd_auth:is_user_exists/2 (src/ejabberd_auth.erl, line 323)
>        in call from ejabberd_auth:try_register/3 (src/ejabberd_auth.erl, line 187)

How to resolve the issue？

Comment: It seems you have an issue in your installation as the module stringprep does not seem to be found.

Comment: I used source code to install ejabberd , used "ejabberdctl register xxx " to add user and login ok,  after login also can add user in web. i need do what other operating?

Comment: Well, you install is broken (either missing ejabberd dependencies or wrong Erlang path). Actually resolution depends on what you missed from the install procedure, I recommend your read official documentation: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not seem to have the `stringprep` dependency installed. the `p1_stringprep` (https://github.com/processone/stringprep) dependency is downloaded automatically during build or included in official packages.

Your error suggest an incorrectly build or incorrectly installed ejabberd.

Comment: I found the p1_stringprep in “ejabberd-master/deps/” after install, and all the beams file(stringprep.beam,  stringprep_app.beam, stringprep_sup.beam) is also in lib/ejabberd/ebin, so whether the path of compiler  is is error? for that:


ejabberd-master$ erl -pa /lib/ejabberd/ebin/

Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.1  (abort with ^G)

1> ejabberd_auth:try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>).

Comment: Your path is clearly wrong. You are only adding /lib/ejabberd/ebin/ to path when launching Erlang. You should have path to all dependencies as well.

Comment: can you tell me how do？ I changed "erl -pa /lib/ejabberd/ebin" to "erl -pa /lib/ejabberd" , that show:exception error: undefined function ejabberd_auth:try_register/3

Comment: You need to add a -pa directive for ejabberd/ebin plus one for each dependancy ebin directory. Note that if you are using ejabberdctl script to launch ejabberd, you will not have this issue as it is done for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer，using ejabberdctl script：”ejabberdctl regster username host password“， is ok。 but my purpose is: by add new module complete register user In the background，my new module for that（mod_useradd_hooca.erl）：

-module(mod_useradd_hooca).
-behaviour(gen_mod).

-export([start/2, stop/1]).
-export([user_add/3]).

start(Host, Opts) -> 
 ok.
 
stop(Host) -> 
 ok.

......
user_add(User, Server, Password) ->
 case ejabberd_auth:try_register(User, Server, Password)
 of
 {error, _Reason} -> error;
  _ -> ok
 end.

Comment: thanks，the issue have solved：I changed to no use erl command。

Comment: Hi @MickaëlRémond. [I am unable to use ejabberd_auth in my helloworld project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220369/i-am-unable-to-use-ejabberd-auth-in-my-helloworld-project). Could you please help. I've trying to make it work for days now. I would very much appreciate any help in any way. I'm trying to write a messaging application in Erlang and Ejabberd.