# I am unable to use `ejabberd_auth` in my **helloworld** project

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am unable to use `ejabberd_auth`  in my **helloworld** project.

```
-behaviour(ejabberd_auth). 
... 
....  
try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>).
```

With that I get the error warning:

```
helloworld.erl:15: Warning: behaviour ejabberd_auth undefined
```

---

---

```
-import(ejabberd_auth, [try_register/3]).  
... 
....  
try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>).
```

With this I get:

```
exception error: undefined function ejabberd_auth:try_register/3
```

---

Why am I unable to access **`ejabberd_auth`**?

I am using IntelliJ Idea, with the Erlang plugin installed.

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

I can get you past that error. Here's how...

When I compile a module in the erlang shell, the compiler creates a `.beam` file in the same directory, which allows me to call functions defined in the module.  In your case, if you cd into the directory:

```
 .../ejabberd/ebin
```

you will see all the ejabberd .beam files, including `ejabberd_auth.beam`.  If you start an erlang shell in that directory, then issue your function call (don't compile anything), you won't get that error anymore.

But, then I get the error:

```
exception error: undefined function jid:nodeprep/1
     in function  ejabberd_auth:validate_credentials/3 (src/ejabberd_auth.erl, line 796)
     in call from ejabberd_auth:try_register/3 (src/ejabberd_auth.erl, line`
```

There is no `jid.beam` file in that directory. But:

```
~/Downloads/ejabberd$ find . -name jid.beam
./deps/xmpp/ebin/jid.beam
```

You are going to have to figure out how to compile your module so that all the ejabberd modules are available to your program.  See: [ejabberd how to compile new module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202550/ejabberd-how-to-compile-new-module).

> I am unable to use ejabberd_auth in my helloworld project.

Are you following a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for the response @7stud. I should have mentioned that I just started learning Erlang and Ejabberd. I am using Intellij and have installed the Erlang plugin for IntelliJ. Would you mind illustrating a step-by-step process for creating a project that successfully calls `try_register(<<"username">>, <<"example.com">>, <<"secret_password">>)? Thank you. You would be a life saver. I'm almost pulling off my hair at this!

Comment: Hi @7stud. I just added a bounty to the question. If you could expound on the answer as per the bounty details, it's yours. Thank you for the help so far. I really appreciate it.